# Switching and clicking on fragments inside navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have made navigation drawer in Android Studio.

Right now each fragment from drawer is leading to nowhere.

I need to know how can I switch between fragments and click on each one

**I know i need to make new fragment, but what method to use so I can click on Settings from navigation drawer so it lead me to fragment Share?**

Here is my code;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction. Just add the Fragment class in each of the Navigation items like below

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
        fragment = new DefaultFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.first_container, fragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragment = new ItemListFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.first_container, fragment).commit();

    }
}
```

at the end of `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`method, you can set the default Fragment to open on Activity load.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    DefaultFragment fragment = new DefaultFragment();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.first_container, fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.`enter code here`
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
        GoogleMap googleMap =getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.alarme){

        } else if (id == R.id.map) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new    mapposta()).commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.parametre) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.